# Parse avro schema from kafka string

Tags: parsing, deserialization, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

How to parse the avro schema encoded as string from kafka in apache spark ?
I am working with apache spark streaming. I have stored my clickstreams in avro format, I used divolte collector to get the clicks. Further i am using kafka to get the clickstreams in real time into the spark streaming. Now i want to deserialise this avro string into a schema for further use by spark.

I used scala case class and genseler.scalavro library for achieving it but wasnt successful. Below is the code

```
case class Change(detectedDuplicate : Boolean,
         detectedCorruption: Boolean,
         firstInSession: Boolean,
         timestamp: Long,
         remoteHost: String,
         referer: String,
         location: String,
         viewportPixelWidth: Int,
         viewportPixelHeight: Int,
         screenPixelWidth: Int,
         screenPixelHeight: Int,
         partyId: String,
         sessionId: String,
         pageViewId: String,
         eventType: String,
         userAgentString: String,
         userAgentName: String,
         userAgentFamily: String,
         userAgentVendor: String,
         userAgentType: String,
         userAgentVersion: String,
         userAgentDeviceCategory: String,
         userAgentOsFamily: String,
         userAgentOsVersion: String,
         userAgentOsVendor: String)

object kafkaParser{

   def parse(event: String): Change = {
      val m = AvroType[Change]
      return new Change(m.schema)// gives me a error at this point unspecified value parameters

     }
 }
```

m.schema gives me the schema for the avro file.

http://genslerappspod.github.io/scalavro/

Please help me how to go forward with this.